# create table with mysql populate with php

Tags: php, mysql, html, wamp

i created tables using mysql. im trying to populate them with my php code.if my tables are empty and i try to insert it gives error, but if i initially add with my sql after that my insert works perfectly. I spent hours but I couldn't fix it..how can I fix this issue
Thanks again

> Notice: Undefined index:

```
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='submitted') {

$project_id = $_POST['project_id'];
$title= $_POST['title'];
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
$parent_project_id = $_POST['parent_project_id'];
$is_completed= $_POST['is_completed'];
$completion_date= $_POST['completion_date'];
$user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
$iproject_id = $_POST['iproject_id'];
$ititle= $_POST['ititle'];
$istart_date = $_POST['istart_date'];
$iend_date = $_POST['iend_date'];
$iparent_project_id = $_POST['iparent_project_id'];
$iis_completed= $_POST['iis_completed'];
$icompletion_date= $_POST['icompletion_date'];
$iuser_id= $_POST['iuser_id'];
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
$selected = $_POST['selected'];
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
$query = "INSERT INTO project (project_id,title,start_date,end_date,parent_project_id,is_completed,completion_date,user_id) VALUES ($iproject_id,'$ititle','$istart_date','$iend_date',$iparent_project_id,$iis_completed,'$icompletion_date',$iuser_id)";
```

Comment: This only looks like bits and pieces.... We have **no idea** what you are doing....

Comment: What line is the undefined index on? You might want to check each line to make sure it actually exists.

Answer (score 2):

Notice: Undefined index: means one of your $_POST[] variables that you are passing does not exist or you misspelled one of them. Compare every $_POST[] to the name attribute of your form maybe you just missed one. try to print_r($_POST) so you can see the correct typos

Answer (score 0):

When using an:

```
INSERT INTO `project` Values ($project_id,$title,$start_date,...etc);
```

The VALUES number and the number of columns in table1 must match ***exactly***.  If you have not set up you tables in phpAdmin correctly that may be your problem

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index:` is not a MySQL error message.

Answer (score 0):

One error is that in the values of your insert query, you use PHP variables such as `$iproject_id` and `$ititle`, while these variables don't exist. You put the POST data's project_id and title in variables called `$project_id` and `$title` in your code (notice the lack of the i after the $ sign).

Would be a good idea to make sure that variable names in your query match the variable names you assign the POST data to.

And PLEASE, sanitize your input before inserting it in your database. Never trust user data, always try to sanitize it for security reasons. `mysql_real_escape_string()` can be your best friend if you want to keep it quick and simple.